# lightbox and ajax problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, lightbox

Whether somebody can help to understand a situation. I have a table, 
data and a marking of which display in the response of Ajax request. In the table there are pictures, it is necessary to use the lightbox to them, I connect a plugin - [Smoothbox](https://github.com/kthornbloom/Smoothbox) and add a certain class to link

```
<a class="sb" href="images/1.png">Image One</a>
```

but when the table is displayed the picture doesn't emerge and simply opens in a new tab, i.e. the script isn't applied to it, though it works, because if to specify the link in static part of the page, everything very beautifully emerges, this plugin not only, also some others were connected and doing the same. In what there can be a reason?

Comment: What you have there is an anchor tag or link, it's contents are text, the link destination is an image ... do you expect to see the image without clicking the link by some majicks?

Comment: Here tag <a> conteins text, as example , in my case inside will be <img> with thumbnail(small preview). But I don't see difference, in both cases  href attribute specifies the URL of an original size image. And when I click on text or on thumb this original image must pop up in smoothbox. In static part of the page it works, in ajax response - nope(